# Python Regex for matching all numbers inside pipes characters

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string:

```
string = "123|1*[123;abc;3;52m;|0|62|0|0|0|12|,399|;abc"
```

I want to match **all** the numbers inside a pair of pipes chars.
So in that case I want the final value of `matches` equal to **`[0, 62, 0, 0, 0, 12]`**:

So far I tried the following regex that only return `[0, 0, 0]`:

```
matches = re.findall("\|(\d+)\|", string)
```

If I replace `+` with `{1,}`, it'll keep returning only `[0, 0, 0]`, but when I replace `+` with `{2,}` it return  `[62, 12]`.

So I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong, thanks for the help

Comment: in `|0|1|` the match is `|0|` and the rest is `1|` which does not match

Comment: Does it need to be in regex? There are probably ways of doing this with ordinary string processing.

Comment: @VPfB Sorry I really don't understand, besides there is no `|0|1|` sequence in my string.
@AkilanManivannan would be better with a regex

Comment: Avoiding using a regex, `matches = [ n for n in string.split('|') if n.isnumeric() ]`, but the result will include any leading or trailing number, such as 123 in your example. Noted here because it may be easier to read, and the leading/trailing number may not be a deal-breaker if you have sufficient control of your input strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once your expression matches |0|, it cannot match the same closing | as the opening | for the next number.

Try using this regular expression - `'\|(\d+)(?=\|)'`.
Here, the `'(?=...)'` part is called a positive lookahead. The match succeeds only if it can match the regex at that point, but no characters will be consumed by the engine.

Comment: Easy and very understandable! I didn't know that positive lookahead regex operator, very powerful. Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=\|)\d+(?=\|)`

Breaking that down:

- `(?<=\|)` is a positive lookbehind that asserts that whatever is captured must be after the `|` symbol
- `\d+` says to look for only digits. The `+` tells it to continue looking until it stops.
- `(?<=\|)` Finally a positive lookahead to tell it to be in between the pipes.

Here's some boilerplate code from regex101:

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=\|)\d+(?=\|)"

test_str = "123|1*[123;abc;3;52m;|0|62|0|0|0|12|,399|;abc"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Here's the output:

```
Match 2 was found at 24-26: 62
Match 3 was found at 27-28: 0
Match 4 was found at 29-30: 0
Match 5 was found at 31-32: 0
Match 6 was found at 33-35: 12
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me to understand better how to use positive lookahead and lookbehind operators!

Answer (score 0):

With `findall` one pipe character `"|"` cannot belong to the number before and to the number after it in the same time. (well, maybe with a lookahead)

Take for example the string `"|0|62|0|"`. The first part `"|0|"` matches the pattern and is added to the results. Then the pattern matching continues with the rest of the string, i.e. with `62|0|`. In this substring a second matchis found: `|0|`. The middle number 62 is not found this way.

I would suggest to split the string, disregard the first and last item, because they are not between two pipe characters. Then check the remaining items if they match `"\d+"`. You can do it with a one-liner, but here it is divided into steps:

```
s1 = "123|1*[123;abc;3;52m;|0|62|0|0|0|12|,399|;abc"
s2 = s1.split('|')
# ['123', '1*[123;abc;3;52m;', '0', '62', '0', '0', '0', '12', ',399', ';abc']
s3 = s2[1:-1]
s4 = [s for s in s3 if re.fullmatch('\d+', s)]
# ['0', '62', '0', '0', '0', '12']
```

Answer (score 0):

i think because it skips the neighbor pattern in-between | if it found the pattern.
Here is a work around:

```
def get_nums(s):
    items = s.split('|')
    found = []
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        if i and item.strip().isdigit():
            found.append(item)
    return found
```